# Transforming a point from one coordinate system to another

Tags: coordinate-systems, transformational-geometry

I am trying to map the position of an object in one image to another. I have four  points in one image with corresponding points in another image so as to bound an area say **A**. Now, if I have points in **A** from one image, how do I get the coordinate of the points in the second image.

It must be noted that the first image has oblique coordinates while the second one is orthogonal. Also, I do not have any other information such as the angle between the two coordinate systems. I only have four points in both the images that encompass all my required points (in area **A**) within them.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the coordinate systems and how they are related to one another. For example, if they are related by a linear transformation then you need to construct the [change of basis matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis).

More work is required for other coordinate systems, e.g. changing from to [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) to [Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system). If a point has polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ then it has Cartesian coordinates
$$(x,y) = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta).$$

Perhaps you might like to give more information about the coordinate systems you're using. In the meantime, take a look at this chapter on [Changes of Coordinates in 2D](http://www.math.utah.edu/online/2210/notes/ch15.pdf).